# Swift NavigationBar is hidden when pass data back main View

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Hello everyone I'am new in swift and I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

> This is Main View

[image]

> and when I Select "TestToNextPage"(**tableViewCell**) will push to
>   SecondView like this photo

[image]

> and when I select VC2 "Test2" button will pass data back to MainView
>   but the NavigationBar will dissmiss

[image]

> I also try this code in MainView and SecondView but is didn't work

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
    }
```

> MainView code for tableViewCell

```
private func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)-> UITableViewCell {
let cellIdentifer = "Cell"
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifer, for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "TestToNextPage"
    cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
    return cell
   }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
 {
     let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
     let SecondViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController")
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(SecondViewController, animated: true)
```

> SecondView Btn code

```
 var MainVC: ViewController
 @IBAction func TestBtn(_ sender: UIButton){
        MainVC?.MainArray = TestArray      //pass TestArray to MainArray
        MainVC?.delegate = self
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SecondSegue", sender: nil)
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "SecondSegue" {
            MainVC = segue.destination as? ViewController
            MainVC?.MainArray = self.TestArray
    }
    func dismissMainViewController(Controller:UIViewController){
        if MainVC == Controller as? ViewController{
            self.TestArray = (MainVC?.MainArray)!
        }
    }
```

**My storyboard** 
[image]

Does anyone have any ideas or Have another best way to do?
thanks for help  mate

Answer (score 0):

Try to embed a Navigation Controller on the Second View Controller in Storyboard and then make your connection from your View Controller to the Navigation Controller you just added.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

Remove the segues from main viewController to secondViewController   and add the code in the action  of TestBtn of  second ViewController

```
@IBAction func TestBtn(_ sender: UIButton){

       self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true))
}
```